# Div to be a percentage width of it's parents, parent.

Tags: html, css, angular

Currently working on a interesting problem where I have the current html structure:

```
<div class='parents-parent'>
    <div class='parent'>
        <div style='width: 50%'></div>
    </div>

    <div class='parent'>
        <div style='width: 25%'></div>
    </div>

    <div class='parent'>
        <div style='width: 25%'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The parent div's are being populated via Angular UI Router and each view/partial has it's own independent width. The 'parent' divs act purely as a dynamic container so they have no width set as this is controlled by the child. However, because of this the percentage width does not work on the child elements.

Is it possible to allow a child element to have a percentage width of the 'parents-parent' div?

Comment: In this case since you are dealing with DIVs and widths, the parent divs will be as wide as the parents-parent div. So I think it will just happen to work here, by coincidence. Is it not working?

Answer (score 2):

Styles cannot affect anything other than an element, or it's children. And there are currently no selectors to allow modification of parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by trying, but it involves *not* having any spaces or linebreaks between the DIV elements in the code (i.e. the whole HTML code in * one* line): Make `parent` an inline-element and the parents children inline-blocks. It's not completely logical, and it might not work on every browser, but at least here (on Firefox Mac) it works...

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  display: inline;
}
.parent>div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='parents-parent'><div class='parent'><div style='width: 50%;background:green;'>A</div></div><div class='parent'><div style='width: 25%;background:red;'>B</div></div><div class='parent'><div style='width: 25%;background:blue;'>C</div></div></div>
```